# How to Measure How Long Running a Code Chunk Takes

Tags: python, benchmarking, timing

I'm trying to figure out how to wrap some parentheses around segments of code I've already written in alternative to the triple parentheses from multi-line `timeit` examples.

This works fine:

```
import timeit
stmt = """\
a = bunch * of
fancy = math ** operations
tada = function(a, fancy)
"""
print("seconds = ", timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, number=1, setup="import numpy as np; import pandas as pd"))
```

source: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/timeit.html#examples

I can't figure out how to get those triple quotes to play nice inside of a custom function I create.

But I'd like to streamline it to something like this:

```
fancy_timing_function(
a = bunch * of
fancy = math ** operations
tada = function(a, fancy)
)
```

where the output is something nice `3 minutes 21.40 seconds`

Any help, suggestions, or alternative solutions (maybe someone has already thought of something like this) from the community are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not write a decorator and use https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/time.html#time.perf_counter ? see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/concurrency_in_python/concurrency_in_python_benchmarking_and_profiling.htm or here: https://medium.com/@prakhar4edu/using-timing-decorator-in-python-b30303895bee .

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I appreciate the suggestion, but when I just tried it, it didn't work with multiple lines of code.
e.g. time.perf_count(    

fancy     

math     

)

Comment: yes, you can only use that on a function. you'd have to write one that collects the operations you want to  time. (e.g.: you can't use assignments as a function argument).

Answer (score 1):

You could define and use a context manager, like this:

```
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def Timer(*args, **kwds):
    start = time.time()
    r = []
    try:
        yield r
    finally:
        r.append(time.time() - start)

with Timer() as t1:
    # Code to be wrapped and timed
    print("x")
    print("y")
    print("z")

with Timer() as t2:
    # More code to be wrapped and timed
    print("xxxxxxxxxxx")

print('Time 1: ' + str(t1[0]))
print('Time 2: ' + str(t2[0]))
```

Result:

```
x
y
z
xxxxxxxxxxx
Time 1: 2.6702880859375e-05
Time 2: 4.291534423828125e-06
```